# Differential equations: Is it just a typo in textbook's solution?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I try to solve a partial differential equation from a Russian textbook. The book also provides a solution. The problem is that the first summand of the book's solution has $x$ multiplied by function of $x$. Is it a typo? 
Shouldn't it be function of $y$ instead of $x$?
$$\frac{\partial^4z}{\partial x^2\partial y^2}=0\implies z=x\varphi_1(x)+\varphi_2(y)+y\varphi_3(x)+\varphi_4(x)$$

Comment: @Parcly Taxel Oh, I am sorry. Thanks for editing

Comment: Obviously there is a typo, otherwise the terms $x\phi_1$ and $\phi_4$ would not differ. And the expression would be asymmetric.

Comment: @Yves Daoust. Thank you. But when I try to check the book's given solution with differentiating  it seems to work as well. Or maybe I'm doing the computations wrong

Comment: Of course it works, my comment says why. $0$ would work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z_{xxyy}=0$$
$$z_{xxy}=\phi_0(x)$$
$$z_{xx}=y\phi_0(x)+\phi_1(x)$$
$$z_x=y\phi_2(x)+\phi_3(x)+\phi_4(y)$$
$$z=y\phi_5(x)+\phi_6(x)+x\phi_4(y)+\phi_7(y)$$